# extract data from http response json

Tags: json, angular, service, data-extraction

I am trying to extract `firstname` fields from a JSON response service with angular and return an array full of firstnames.

This is the the JSON object:

```json
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "skipped": 0,
        "successful": 1,
        "total": 1
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "BKZujHgB0urOc7uDCrf5",
                "_index": "names",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "firstname": "Alicia"
                },
                "_type": "_doc"
            },
            {
                "_id": "BaZujHgB0urOc7uDL7e2",
                "_index": "names",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "firstname": "Alice"
                },
                "_type": "_doc"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "total": {
            "relation": "eq",
            "value": 2
        }
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 4
}
```

And this is my `service.ts`:

```js
public autoComplete(name: string): Observable<Output> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('name', name);

    return this.httpClient.get<Output>(this.host, {params});
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code for your service.ts. It's missing a lot of things, and it looks like you are asking the comminuty to do the job for you. What have you tried ? What didn't worked ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after subscribing to your service:

```js
let array = response.hits.hits.map(h=>h._source.firstname);
```

Normally you will get an array like `["Alicia", "Alice"]`.